# Is the following Variadic template behavior inconsistent?

Tags: c++, string, templates, variadic-templates

I was trying the following example to understand variadic templates and found the behaviour somewhat inconsistent.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
T adder(T v) {  
  return v;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
T adder(T first, Args... args) {    
  return first + adder(args...);
}

int main()
{   
    long sum = adder(1, 2, 3, 8, 7); //Works
    cout << sum << endl;

    string s1 = "xx", s2 = "aa", s3 = "bb", s4 = "yy";

    string ssum = adder(s1, s2, s3, s4); //Works
    cout << ssum << endl;

    string ssum2 = s1 + s2 + "3" + "4"; //Works as operator '+' is defined in string class for const char*
    cout << ssum2 << endl;

    string ssum3 = adder(s1, s2, "3", "4"); //Does not work. Expected as  binary 'operator+' is not defined for string and const char*
    cout << ssum3 << endl;

    string ssum4 = adder("3", "4"); //Does not work. Expected as  binary 'operator+' is not defined for const char* and const char*
    cout << ssum4 << endl;

    string ssum5 = adder(s1, s2, "3"); //Works!!! 
    cout << ssum5 << endl;  

}
```

Calling `adder` for `ssum3` and `ssum4` fails but works for `ssum5`. Is this behaviour consistent? Is it happening because the last argument for `ssum5` is converted into `string` at the final iteration?

Comment: Hint: a+b+c is the same as (a+b)+c which is in general different from a+(b+c).

Comment: the error in your comment is wrong,the problem is that there is no `operator+` for `const char*` and `const char*`

Comment: ...there is an `operator+` for `string + const char*`, otherwise none but the first would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it with `std::common_type`.

As other have noted, this has to do with the order of your recursion.

```
adder(s1, s2, "3")
```

Is the same as:

```
s1 + adder(s2, "3")
```

which works since this is the same as (which sums `std::strings`, and also sums `std::string` with a `const char*`, which are legal) :

```
s1 + (s2 + ("3")))
```

On the other hand

```
adder(s1, s2, "3", "4");
```

obviously can't work since it is the same as (which ends up adding two `const char*`, which is illegal):

```
s1 + (s2 + ("3" + ("4")))
```

To overcome this you should use `std::common_type`, which will perform all additions in the common type (which is `std::string` in this case):

```
template<typename T>
T adder(const T & v) {  
  return v;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
T adder(const T & first, const Args &... args) {    
  return first + adder<typename std::common_type<T, Args...>::type>(args...);
}
```

Another option is to use C++17 fold expressions (if you have C++17):

```
template <typename ... Args>
typename std::common_type<Args...>::type
adder2(const Args & ... args)
{
    using type = typename std::common_type<Args...>::type;
    return (type(args) + ... );
}
```

The disadvantage is that it causes copy constructors for types such as strings, and that it requires C++17. It is possible to get rid of the extra construction (including for common base classes), by using a helper function:

```
template <typename Target, typename Source>
typename std::enable_if< ! std::is_base_of<Target, Source>::value, 
                         Target>::type 
toType(const Source & source)
{
    return source;
}
template <typename Target, typename Source>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Target, Source>::value, 
                        const Target&>::type
toType(const Source & source)
{
    return source;
}
template <typename ... Args>
typename std::common_type<Args...>::type
addder3(const Args & ... args)
{
    using type = typename std::common_type<Args...>::type;
    return (toType<type>(args) + ... );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Is it happening because the last argument for `ssum5` is converted into `string` at the final iteration?

No, it works because [`std::operator+(std::basic_string)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) is overloaded to take a `std::string` and raw string (`const char*`). Given `s2` is a `std::string`, then both `s2 + "3"` and `"3" + s2` work fine. So `ssum5` works because at last recursion it'll be interpreted as `s2 + "3"`, which is fine.

The problem is that you can't pass two successive raw strings to `adder`. For `ssum3` and `ssum4` you're passing `"3"` and `"4"`, at last they'll be interpreted as `"3" + "4"`, which won't work obviously.

Answer (score 1):

ssum3 is `adder(s1, adder(s2, adder("3", adder("4"))))`

ssum5 is `adder(s1, adder(s2, adder("3")))`

The first case contains the instantation `adder("3", adder("4"))`, which expands out to `"3" + "4"` ultimately, which obviously doesn't work.

The second case doesn't ever try to add two `const char*`s together, so it's fine.